# Inherit web.xml from jar file

Tags: servlets, web.xml

We have many web applications that have shared setting (the web.xml and servlets are the same) and just Spring routes requests to different beans (BlazeDS & Spring).

My question is: is there a way to place web.xml in a shared jar? or another way to have the common web.xml exist once so it can come from a framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Servlet 3 specification support for web.xml includes.
Which means that you can split your giant configuration file to few smaller: spring-config.xml, blazeds-config.xml etc

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. Now how can I make one of them come from outside location?

Comment: I see on the Servlet specification that web fragment can come from jar files, which looks like what I need. I will check it out